# Webscraping in R: How to follow a "next" button and scrape the page?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm currently working with data provided by https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22Labor%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100.

I would also prefer solutions to rely on the following packages -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
```

My end goal is to grab every every article from the first 5 pages to feed into a function that will parse it and produce a dataframe. I would like to start on the first page and, I assume, use the "next" button to move across all 5 pages, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around ways to do that that don't leave out the first page. I've seen a variety of options like "follow_link" and "sprintf" as well as "html_session" used in similar contexts, but haven't been able to understand those examples well enough to generalize them and then use them here.

Looking at a similar example, I was under the impression this structure ought to work if fed the right information in the html_nodes function. No combination of tags that I've tried thus far, however, has succeeded in the way that the example showed.

```
source_col <- https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22Labor%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100

map_df(1:4, function(i){

    page <- read_html(sprintf(source_col, i))

    data.frame(Doc_ID = html_text(html_nodes(page, ""))) 

  }) -> Labor_References
```

If someone could give me any guidance on alternative ways to proceed (and explain briefly how they work?), or how to fix this existing chunk, I would be extremely grateful. I apologize if anything about this is unclear - I'm a relative newcomer to R and coding in general.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to the next page, you will see that the url updates to include `&page=1`. We can make use of this (starting at page=0) and loop through each page by updating the url.

```r
library(dplyr)
root <- 'https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=%22Labor%22&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=&items_per_page=100&page='
pages <- 5
df <- tibble()

for(i in seq_len(pages)){
  # pages start from 0 so subtract 1
  page <- paste0(root,i-1) %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('table') %>%
    html_table()

  tmp <- page[[1]]

  df <- bind_rows(df, tmp)
}

df
## A tibble: 500 x 3
#   Date        Related        `Document Title`                                                                                
#   <chr>       <chr>          <chr>                                                                                           
# 1 Dec 05, 18… James K. Polk  Fourth Annual Messageof affairs in California. Labor commands a most exorbitant …               
# 2 Jan 24, 18… Franklin Pier… "Special Messagetemporarily to the \"Shawnee Manual Labor School\" (or mission). and …"         
# 3 Dec 03, 18… Abraham Linco… First Annual Message                                                                            
# 4 Dec 01, 18… Abraham Linco… Second Annual Messageis mathematically certain. Labor is like any other commodity …
```